# How to detect current path?

Tags: url-routing

I am developing my first standalone web-application and i faced the problem with routing. For example my index is located in `sites/folder/folder/index.php`, so url for it would be `http://site.com/folder/folder/index.php`. So what is the best way to get all after `index.php`? Just use `for` or `foreach` until `index.php` is found or may be there is a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried parsing urls by [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)? This may help you.